# how to get json_query to search for pattern in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I am trying to extract the data from a JSON output obtained from API call using `uri` module. The data contains some key value pairs. The format is like below

```
item : "name-of-the-item"
"json" : {
    "data": {
          "First.Name": "First Name"
          "Middle.Name": "Middle Name"
          "Last.Name": "Last Name"
          "Home.Address": "Address "
          "Work.Address": "Address 2"
          "AuthID": ""
           }
}
```

I am trying to group and output data with extension `.Name` so that I get the following outputs
First.Name, Middle.Name, Last.Name

Or list the Addresses with `.Address` which would lead to outputs of Home.Address and Work.Address

my playbook

```
- name: extract json data from url
  uri:
    url: https://api.url
    method: GET
    return_content: true
    Content-Type: application/json
  register: data_from_url

- name: display the names
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ data_from_url.json.data | json_query ('Name') }}"
```

however, the query gives me an error. I tried looking into the JMESpath examples, but i cannot find anything which is used to match an extension in the JSON. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, naming dict elements with an identifier containing a dot is a bad idea in ansible, and more generally in json/yaml. I suggest you change this if you can because it will probably add a lot of confusion in the future on your project.

Meanwhile, taking your current data as is, `json_query` is not the tool you need in this circumstance. Basically what you have to do is to filter out all the keys which do not have `.Name` in their name.

Here is a quick example to achieve this. The global idea is to:

1. transform your dict to a list of `{key: keyname, value: keyvalue}` elements
2. filter out all elements where `keyname` does not match your criteria with `selectattr` (or eventually `rejectattr`)
3. transform the filtered list back to a dictionary.

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    example_data: {
      "First.Name": "First Name",
      "Middle.Name": "Middle Name",
      "Last.Name": "Last Name",
      "Home.Address": "Address ",
      "Work.Address": "Address 2",
      "AuthID": ""
  }

  tasks:
    - name: Show only elements containing ".name"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ example_data | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '.*\\.Name') | list | items2dict }}"
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show only elements containing ".name"] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "First.Name": "First Name",
        "Last.Name": "Last Name",
        "Middle.Name": "Middle Name"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I unfortunately have no control over the JSON data that comes in from the API. I used `set_facts` to get the data be used as vars. 
I tried testing your example, however, in Ansible version < 2.10 , it gives error `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "items2dict requires a list, got <class 'generator'> instead."}`

Comment: I just edited the answer with a fix that will work in ansible 2.10 and below as well.

Comment: Thank you. it works nicely. something i should have looked up. Just a quick question, is it possible to extract only the key and loop it to print the names using `loop` function?

Comment: You have all the needed elements in the above answer. Simply loop on `example_data | dict2items | list` and debug `item.key`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) for more information